# meshlab offset mesh produces no vertices or faces

Tags: offset, mesh

I cannot get this Filter to produce any vertices or faces :-(
I have followed this turorial: http://www.soliforum.com/topic/13709/how-to-hollow-out-a-model/
I have tried various values for Precision and for Offset.

[SCREENSHOT showing model and resulting offset attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMipq.jpg)
-and- [SCREENSHOT of my Filter settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuMjL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screenshot, your offset value is way too large for the size of your mesh - you are trying to offset -78 units but your mesh is only 133 and 62 units on the smaller axes.